# How to show emojis in vscode ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, emoji

I am trying to display the emojis in VSCode from a computer with Ubuntu version 20.04, but pressing the key combination 'Windows' + '.' (period), it does not perform any action, I have already been investigating but I have not found anything about it that gives me a solution, so I still cannot show the emojis, I do not want to install the exemptions in VSCode that by means of: (colon ) shows you the emoji as it causes me noise when programming, it is worth mentioning that I have tried on the windows operating system and the combination works without problems.

I hope and you can help me if I need to install an extra library or if the key combination to show the emojis in Ubuntu is different.

First of all, Thanks.

Comment: Emojis are unicode characters. [On Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/31283/349837) check Ctrl+Shift+u, then the hexadecimal number of the emoji, and enter or space.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me
Installed **:emojisense:** extension
press **Ctrl + i** for opening the extension search bar

Comment: This one works on linux.

Answer (score 5):

Neither `ctrl +.` nor `win +.` not working.
As of today, there is no such option without installing an additional extension like `:emojisense:` which has many options, including disabling some bothersome dependencies. I tried it and it's quite okay.I also set up for this extension a hotkey under `win +.` in Visual Studio Code ;-)
I hope You will like it ! Best regards ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is not ideal, but if you don't use it very frequently, you can obviously copy-paste the emoji from any other text.

For example you open `gedit`, right click and `Insert Emoji`
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS5wU.gif)

After that you simply copy and paste the emoji in VSCode ️

Comment: That is a lot of work just to get emojis working. But it works so, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install :emojisense:

shortcut: Ctrl + i